# How to skip a folder from git checkout using batch

Tags: git, batch-file

How do I skip a folder from git checkout using batch. This is my batch file. I have some 35 folders. However, I do not wish to checkout a specific folder. I need to skip the checkout on this folder.

```
@echo off

set project=%1


call :THISISWHEREITHAPPENS
goto :eof
w
:THISISWHEREITHAPPENS

for /D %%f in (*.*) do (
echo current project: 
echo %%f
if %%f == "folder_name_that_I_want_to_skip_as_string"
    goto skip
else
    goto chkout

:skip
    echo skippep
    goto cont
:chkout
    echo : git checkout release_branch
    cd %%f
    git checkout release_branch     
    goto cont
:cont
    echo -------------------------------------------------------------
    cd ..

)
pause
```

Comment: Right at the beginning of your script you have `set project=%1`, but then don't use it in your code. Are you supposed to be `CD`ing to it? or is it to be removed completely?

Comment: @Compo : It is to be removed completely.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you have over-censored you code, so it's difficult to determine exactly what your problem is. You also don't say what it's doing that it shouldn't be doing or not doing that it should.

We're left to make assumptions, which are always dangerous.

So the glaring problem with the code you've posted is that `if` is very literal, and the two arguments must be **exactly** the same to be declared equal.

Hence,

```
if %%f == "folder_name_that_I_want_to_skip_as_string"
```

should be

```
if "%%f" == "folder_name_that_I_want_to_skip_as_string"
```

or

```
if /I "%%f" == "folder_name_that_I_want_to_skip_as_string"
```

if you want the comparison to be case-insensitive.

Since you're aware of the exact contents of `%%f` as they are displayed, then I'm assuming that the strings seem to match, except for the quotes.

Comment: %%f is a variable and I thought %%f should be holding the name of the folder during the iteration.

Comment: I will try removing the quotes.
I tried removing the quotes but that was not helpful either.

Comment: How about just doing as I suggested and enclose `%%f` in quotes in the `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

A structural rewrite:

```bat
@Echo Off

Call :ThisIsWhereItHappens

GoTo :EOF

:ThisIsWhereItHappens
For /D %%A In (*) Do (
    If /I Not "%%A"=="DirectoryNameString" (
        PushD "%%A"
        Echo current project: 
        Echo %%A
        Echo : git checkout release_branch
        git checkout release_branch
        Echo -------------------------------------------------------------
        PopD
    ) Else Echo Skipped 
)
Pause
```